# ORA - 06550 String Literal too long : while passing Large Json Data into Procedure

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I have a large Json data. I got that data through a clob parameter into my procedure. when i am processing the json data i got an error string literal too long. How can i resolve this issue? Everything is worked as expected when the json data has less number of codes.
Thanks in advance

I tried with different sized Json data. Above 32767 characters is not accepting. Is there any idea to solve/override this issue ?

I used below code,
create or replace procedure proc_json data(json_string clob) is
begin
dbms_output.put_line(length(json_string));
end;

Comment: I'm guessing that the error comes when you try to call this method in code you haven't posted.  I'm guessing that in that code you are trying to pass a string literal to the procedure, which would be a `varchar2` rather than passing a `clob`.  If those guesses are accurate, the solution would depend on where you actually want to get the JSON data from.  You could read the data from a file into a local `clob` variable, you could write code to append multiple 32k chunks to produce the `clob`, etc.

Comment: you need to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

When you use JSON functions to process the data, add the `RETURNING JSON` or `RETURNING CLOB` options; otherwise the default is to return a `VARCHAR2` data type which is limited to 4000 characters in SQL or 32767 in PL/SQL.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (a, b, c) AS
SELECT LEVEL*1e6, LEVEL*1e7, LEVEL*1e8 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100;
```

Then:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
         JSON_OBJECT(
           KEY 'a' VALUE a,
           KEY 'b' VALUE b,
           KEY 'c' VALUE c
         )
         ORDER BY a
       ) AS result
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

```
ORA-40478: output value too large (maximum: 4000)
```

But if you specify the `RETURNING` (and, in this case, `FORMAT`) clauses:

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
         JSON_OBJECT(
           KEY 'a' VALUE a,
           KEY 'b' VALUE b,
           KEY 'c' VALUE c
           RETURNING CLOB
         ) FORMAT JSON
         ORDER BY a
         RETURNING CLOB
       ) AS result
FROM   table_name
```

Then the output is

| RESULT |
| --- |
| [{"a":1000000,"b":10000000,"c":100000000},{"a":2000000,"b":20000000,"c":200000000},{"a":3000000,"b":30000000,"c":300000000},{"a":4000000,"b":40000000,"c":400000000}, ... {"a":98000000,"b":980000000,"c":9800000000},{"a":99000000,"b":990000000,"c":9900000000},{"a":100000000,"b":1000000000,"c":10000000000}] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EizmAcG7)